# Get all html tags(parent and child tags) with id and class name with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anybody knows how can I get all the HTML tags that exist in a page?

var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

This will get all the tags, but my requirement is

- get a first parent tag and all the child tags under it
- get the next parent tag and all the child tags under it and so on

I need to get the tags in a kind of tree-structure. Prefer to do that with Javascript or JQuery.

**For example:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example Page</title>
  </head>
  <body id="x" class="something">
    <h1 style="somestyle">Blabla</h1>
    <div id="id">
      <table id="formid">
        <tr>
          <td id="1"></td>
          <td id="2"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**Should Return:**

html

1. head->title
2. body-->h1,(div-->table-->tr-->td,td)

Comment: *"Javascript or JQuery"* jQuery is not a language. You mean "...in JavaScript with the DOM directly or with jQuery."

Comment: *"I need to get the tags in a kind of tree-structure."* They aren't tags, they're elements. (A "tag" is a textual concept.) And they're already *in* a tree structure: The DOM.

Comment: I need to store these elements in a list/var to use in in a different concept. For example suppose,
 I get head element in first loop and assign that element to a var and see if there is any child elements under head and assign those value to another variable.

Comment: My answer shows you what you'd use to do that. (I thought you wanted an array rather than just variables within the loop, but adapting it is easy.)

Comment: Idd use the `document.documentElement.children[0].children[0].children` and so on (and children.length if you wish).

Comment: Is there any way to check nested children elements using function?
'<body>
<p><strong>strong p with <i>italic</i> word</strong> paragraph</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.body.children;
  var txt = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
     txt = txt + c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
  }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</body>' -- This is getting me only first child elements. Can I get strong and i with more nested elements, which are inside first p element ?

Answer (score 0):

`document.documentElement` is the root of the tree (`html`). You can then get all of its child elements via `children` (`childNodes` would include non-Element children), and get their descendants in document order using `querySelectorAll("*")`:

```
var results = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.documentElement.children,
    function(element) {
    return element.querySelectorAll("*");
});
```

[Live example](http://output.jsbin.com/mazecovicu)

`results` will be an array with an entry for each direct child of the `html` element, where each element is a `NodeList`. If you want an array of arrays, you can use `Array.from` on the result of `querySelectorAll` (polyfilling it if necessary, as it's relatively new).

Of course there are a dozen ways to spin this. For instance, an array of objects instead:

```
var results = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.documentElement.children,
    function(element) {
    return {
         element: element,
         descendants: Array.from(element.querySelectorAll("*"))
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function may help you. If you are using it on server side, create a DTO with key and value as attibute as String datatype. You can choose body or html as base.

```
function myFunction() {
    var c = document.body.children;
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    var ListOfMap=[];


    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
       var map={};
       var key=c[i].tagName;
     //console.log("key::::"+key);
   //  console.log("value::::"+document.getElementsByTagName(c[i].tagName)[0].textContent);
       if(key !== 'undefined' && typeof key !== undefined){
           map.key=c[i].tagName;
           map.value=document.getElementsByTagName(c[i].tagName)[0].textContent;
           txt=txt+ document.getElementsByTagName(c[i].tagName)[0].textContent+"</br>";
       }
       ListOfMap.push(map);
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ListOfMap));
    return ListOfMap;
}
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/5FIbffmTZ3xkRG5GCBhK?p=preview